# I want a similar screen (one on top of other) like following to complete my weather app made using flutter . Can anyone please help me out?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[image: This type of screen one on top of other]

I want this type of screen one on top of other and the previous screen should be lightly blurred or it should slightly darkens

Comment: Take a look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html, there is also example in DartPad

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

You could use 'ModalBottomSheet' or even 'DraggableScrollableSheet' if a list is associated.

[ModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Container(
           // widgets 
        ),
      );
    });
```

[DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
               // widgets
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Whats wrong here ?